# Use pattern mattching to detect x is not a or not b

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I need to check if some value is not one or another and I want to use `or` with pattern matching. The "forward" one - `x is a or b` is easy:

```cs
int GetInt() => 3;

if (GetInt() is 3 or 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("3 or 4");
}
```

But negation I can't figure out. I have tried:

```cs
if (GetInt() is not 4 or 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("not 3 or 4 #1");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Succcess");
}
```

Or

```cs
if (GetInt() is not 3 or not 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("not 3 or 4 #2");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Succcess");
}
```

But both print the first statement (the `not 3 or 4...`).

Also IDE grays out different parts of the code:

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use parenthesis:

```cs
if (GetInt() is not (3 or 4))
{
    Console.WriteLine("not 3 or 4 #2");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

Demo [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ65IJwAoBEgPBuAg+/gJQDc6AllMAAQDiApsAJJ25n0C8AfPQDMVNNQBm9XC3adu1AM70oAewa5B9ZWHoAWMmXQBvdAEgsefCoYatu+gGIE5EQF90zADbzmR0+YIAyhAAxsHM8vLO6C5AA=)

Comment: Oh my..... That was so easy.... Thank you!